# Способы определить утечку памяти

Tags: c, unix, утечка-памяти, linux

Суть вопроса проста. Какие способы/инструменты есть для определения что память у нас утекла?
**ANSI C.**
**Для Unix-подобных ОС**
**x64-86**

Нагуглил [Hans Boehm garbage collector](URL), но он то ли не работает с Linux x64, то ли я совсем его криво использую - всё время выдаёт 65536 на GC_get__heap_size().

crtdbg не подходит из-за привязки к MSVS.
Изначально это была задача определить правильно ли я удаляю дерево, но переросло в этот вопрос.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Одна из программ Valgrinda, Memcheck, насколько я понимаю, соответствует вашим требованиям.

Comment: Valgrind отлично помог. Благодарю)